# Why do we need $\text{Re}(s) > 0$ for the argument $s$ of the Riemann $\zeta(s)$ function?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

In our class we are looking at the Riemann $\zeta(s)$ function $\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}$, derived in connection with the Euler $\Gamma(s)$ function discussed previously.

> Integral formula: $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1}e^{-nx}dx = \ ... \ = \frac{\Gamma(s)}{n^s}$, if Re$(s) >0$.
> Hence $\zeta(s)\Gamma(s)= \ ... \ = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1} dx$, (true for Re$(s) > 1)$.

(some details omitted)

Can I have some explanation on the two conditions on Re$(s)$ above? What would happen if Re$(s)$ is less than or equal to the stated values?

Comment: If $\Re s\le 0$, then the first integral does not converge at the $x=0$ endpoint. Whatever formula is being used for $\zeta(s)$ in the $\cdots$ is probably valid only for $\Re s>1$ (for similar convergence reasons), and hence the process of using those formulas to get a new formula for $\zeta(s)\Gamma(s)$ will only yield a result when $\Re s>1$ as well.

Comment: For the first formula, the left integral doesn’t converge if the real part of $s$ isn’t positive. For the second formula, $\zeta$ is undefined if the real part of $s $ isn’t greater than $1$.